# How can I uninstall the new Ubuntu One systray indicator?

Tags: ubuntu-one, indicator, 13.04

I though the new Ubuntu One indicator for 13.04 would mean good news, but the truth is that I think it's not as good as the one [I use in 12.10](http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-precise-install-system-tray-indicator-on-panel-for-ubuntu-one). Is there some way of removing it and just keep the one I all ready use? Right now I got two identical cloud icons in the systray and it's just redundant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to remove the `indicator-sync` package, then log out and back in.

Comment: Instead of relogin you can `killall indicator-sync-service`